# gcc - warning: implicit declaration of function 'get_int'

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cs50, gcc-warning

I am doing the cs50 course and decided to run the code from there on my pc.

I have the following code:

```
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        //gets an integer from a user
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 8);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n * 2 + 2; j++)
        {
            //prints hashes only if j is more or equal to n - 1 
            if (j >= n - i && j <= n - 1)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            //prints empty spaces to make the pyromide right alinged
            else if (j <= n - i)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }

            //makes empty spaces between two pyromids
            else if (j >= n - 1 && j <= n + 1)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }

            //adds hashes for the second pyromid
            else if (j >= n + 2 && j <= n + 1 + i)
            {
                printf("#");
            }

        }
        //starts a new line after finishing the code
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and when I try to compile it this happens:

```
gcc cs50.o mario.c -o mario.exe -std=c99 -lcs50
mario.c: In function 'main':
mario.c:10:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'get_int' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         n = get_int("Height: ");
         ^
C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcs50
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using gcc compiler on a Windows PC. I also downloaded the cs50 library from [here](https://mirror.cs50.net/library50/c/) and tried in many ways to compile and run my code.

For instance, I tried to build an intermediate file from cs50.c and cs50.h by using this line `gcc -c cs50.c` it created an object named cs50.o, linking it didn't work either. The last attempt to link the cs50 library with this `-lcs50` did nothing as well.

I tried to use the following methods, but they too didn't work for me:

- [importing C library in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214170/importing-c-library-in-windows/15234362#15234362)
- [How to link the cs50 C library in gcc on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432721/how-to-link-the-cs50-c-library-in-gcc-on-windows/57439227#57439227)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't add text output as image. Instead copy&paste it as plain text into the question.

Comment: Please copy&paste the error message as text to the question. Please show the exact commands you use to compile the program. Is the file you show in the question `cs50.c` or `mario.c`? Where is function `get_int` defined?

Comment: `-lcs50` looks good, but you must build and install the cs50 library and make sure that the proper include files and libraries are found. That may involve the `-I` and `-L` flags to extend the search paths for include and library files.

Comment: It is not only a problem with the library. There is also a compiler warning indicating that the declaration of `get_int` is missing. Normally `cs50.h` is included using `<cs50.h>` instead of `"cs50.h"`. Do you have an own header in your folder?

Comment: @Gerhardh <cs50.h> would mean to look for it in compiler's system paths, "cs50.h" is good provided that the library files are in the same folder as the code file, anyways, if the compiler couldn't find it, it would show No such file error or something like that

Comment: @MovsarBekaev yes, but if the right header is used, there should not be a missing declaration. Therefore I suspect some local file hiding the "official" header.

Comment: The names of the CS50 functions were, once upon a time, `GetInt()` etc.  They changed a couple of years ago.  Have you looked in the `cs50.h` file to check that `get_int()` is declared in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonathan Leffler As you suggested it was because of that. Thank you a lot for helping with this problem. Now compiler works and I can run the program.

Comment: Glad the problem is resolved.  You might want to contact the CS50 admins to let them know the mirror sites have antiquated versions of the source code (or at least one of them does).  If you know which site you downloaded from, so much the better.  And, I must admit, I'm surprised that this was the problem — but you seemed to be doing it mostly right, so it was worth asking.